# deploying is failed in heroku with nodejs

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, heroku

Error message

App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/Murali5665/tinderclone-1
bash: /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/6808d9bafd7cf888affdcbfa3b24d7368d0a7618/bin/detect: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

You have told Heroku to use your app's source code as a buildpack.

[A buildpack is a very specific thing](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks):

> Buildpacks are responsible for transforming deployed code into a slug, which can then be executed on a dyno. Buildpacks are composed of a set of scripts, and depending on the programming language, the scripts will retrieve dependencies, output generated assets or compiled code, and more. This output is assembled into a slug by the [slug compiler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler).
>
> Heroku’s support for Ruby, Python, Java, Clojure, Node.js, Scala, Go and PHP is implemented via a set of open source buildpacks.

It is uncommon to provide your own custom buildpack, and your source code is not valid as a buildpack.

[Clear your configured buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-buildpacks-clear):

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
```

Then deploy again. Heroku will see your `package.json` and automatically select the Node.js buildpack.